# How to give input to the middle layer in keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I want to use pre-trained vgg-19 after popping last layer then adding 2 FC(Dense) layer. I want to give input to one of these FC layer a binary variable(Male or female). How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need a two-input and one-output network, where each input has its own feature extraction and both features fused before predicting the final output.

Below is an example.

```python
import keras
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from keras.models import Model

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define your new inputs
# Here I pretend that your new task is a classification task over 100 classes
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gender_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='gender_input')
image_input  = Input(shape=(224,224,3), name='image_input')
num_classes  = 100
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# define your pretrained feature extraction
# you may do something different than below
# but the point here is to have a pretrained model for `featex`
# so you may define it differently
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pretrained   = VGG19()
featex       = Model( pretrained.input, pretrained.layers[-2].output, name='vgg_pop_last' )
# consider to freeze all weights in featex to speed-up training
image_feat   = featex( image_input )
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# From here, you may play with different network architectures
# Below is just one example
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
image_feat   = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='image_fc')( image_feat )
gender_feat  = Dense(16, activation='relu', name='gender_fc')( gender_input )
# mix information from both information
# note: concatenation is only one of plausible way to mix information
concat_feat  = Concatenate(axis=-1,name='concat_fc')([image_feat, gender_feat])
# perform final prediction
target       = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='pred_class')( concat_feat )
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Here is your new model which contains two inputs and one new target
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
model = Model( inputs=[image_input, gender_input], outputs=target, name='myModel')

print model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse **old_model's** layers from 5th to output as a new model, You need to rebuild the model like this, the key point is define a **Input**, and pass it to the 5th layer. it may looks like this:
    
    `FC = ... # your FC layers
    old_model = models.load_model(MODEL_DIR)
    old_model.layers.pop(-1) # Get rid of the classification layer
    for i in range(4): # Get rid of the first 4 layer
      old_model.layers.pop(0) # care pop index while iterating
    input = Input(shape=(INPUT_DIM,))
    new_model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=FC(old_model(input)))`